# Trouble Using LocalStorage to Store Cookie in Mobile Web App

Tags: html, session, cookies, local-storage

Gurus of SO

I have posted a web app to the iOS Home Screen & want to not have to login each time the app opens up. So I am trying to push the cookie into LocalStorage.

I am using the following code to try to store my cookies in LocalStorage for a mobile web app (code copied from iphone web app ruby gem). But somehow its not working. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
var RESEND_REQUEST = {{RESEND}};

function isFullScreen(){
  return navigator.userAgent.match(/WebKit.*Mobile/) &&
         !navigator.userAgent.match(/Safari/);
}

if(isFullScreen()){
  if(document.cookie == ''){
    var storedValues = localStorage.getItem('__cookie__');
      if(storedValues){
        var values = storedValues.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i < values.length; i++)
          document.cookie = values[i];
      }
      document.cookie = '_cookieset_=1';

    if(RESEND_REQUEST){
      window.location.reload();
    }

  }  

  var lastCookie = null;
  setInterval(function(){
    if(lastCookie != ''+document.cookie){
      lastCookie = ''+document.cookie;
      localStorage.setItem('__cookie__', ''+document.cookie);
    }
  },1000);

}
})()
```

Comment: Check whether are you running the same problem as I'm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075530/data-stored-into-localstorage-isnt-available-afterwards and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077101/iphone-localstorage-quota-exceeded-err-issue If yes then possible that the reason why the  above code doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

There are couple thing that does fit in the above code

**1**. `if(document.cookie == '')`
     The above statement not always suppose **return true** even when you are opening your web_app from iOS Home Screen for **the first time** i.e the document.cookie does contain some value (junk though but still) even opening from Home screen(atleast what I found). I urge you to prompt the same with alert

Something like `alert(document.cookie)` before running into the above mention`if clause` 
 If yes(`document.cookie does contain some value`) then I guess you need to fix the above if clause something like this

```
>       if(!document.cookie.match(/_session_id/) ) {
>          // Rest of the code goes here
>       }
```

if your using ActiveRecord::Base.session_store

or

```
>     if (!document.cookie.match(/{{YOUR SESSION KEY}}/) {
>               // Rest of the code goes here
>      }
```

your Session Key if using Cookie Store "the following key can be found my looking at the `config/initializer/session_store.rb` file

**2**. As notice the below code

> ```
>  localStorage.setItem('__cookie__', ''+document.cookie)
> ```

does make sense when reading though it but there is twist to it
  one would except the **document.cookie to contain cookie for the application**  maintained
  and stored by the browser but as I notice that **document.cookie** does not turn out to be same

e.g browser stored the following cookie for my application

"__cookieset=1;KBD=0en-3;_session_id=896c455928f3dd9e7bb0b660efb7063c"

but when inspected the document.cookie I found it to be contain

```
"__cookieset=1;KBD=0en-3;"
```

Notice that document.cookie doesnot contain `"_session_id=896c455928f3dd9e7bb0b660efb7063c"`

Which is must as It used by various **authorization gem(devise or authlogic)** to determine whether the current user has a  valid session ?

so I request you store the cookie from the request object obtain from `Rack::Request.new(env)` 
into the localStorage

**3**. The **middleware placement** make sure your placing middleware at right place.

If your using ActiveRecord::Base.session_store I guess the patch code of the same gem can be found [here](https://github.com/meetme2meat/rack_iphone) solve your purpose