# Store Cookie in iPhone LocalStorage

Tags: html, session, cookies, local-storage

I read that the only way to get my php/js web app not to reset each time the visitor click on icon is to put the cookies in localstorage. I did read [Trouble Using LocalStorage to Store Cookie in Mobile Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381632/trouble-using-localstorage-to-store-cookie-in-mobile-web-app/9469581#9469581) who had the same issue but there is no clear solution  or at least i don't manage to make it work. I can't figure out how to do something operational from there. Has anyone implemented someting that he could show the code for.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by reset you mean go to the start page (or more precisely the page in which the user choose to download the app), this can be achieved in several ways, **cookies and localStorage** are two nice and simple ways. Since I'm already storing loads of data in localStorage in my guestlist web app, i choose to use cookies for this. **Here's how I did it:**

*(N.B. I'm using the jquery cookie plugin so if you're about to copy paste this code, make sure to implement the plugin first. Let's get down to business)*

In each seperat page, set/overwrite the cookie "userLocaltion" with the "current location":

```
$.cookie("userLocation", "addGuest", { expires: 1 }); //persists for 1 day
```

Similarly, call the function userPreviousLocaltion() at the top of each page and create the function using switch case (shown below). Since most of my subpages lie within my index.html, I'm triggering a click on a button rather than sending the user to separate pages:

```
function userPreviousLocaltion() {
var userLocation = $.cookie("userLocation");

switch (userLocation) {
case "addGuest":
  $('#addGuestFooterWrap').trigger('click');
  break;
case "stats":
  $('#statsFooterWrap').trigger('click');
  break;
case "utilities":
  $('#settingsFooterWrap').trigger('click');
  break;
case "bookings":
  $('#bookingsFooterWrap').trigger('click');
  break;
case "guestlist":
  window.location = "guestlist.html";
  break;
default:
    console.log("do nothing, stay on first page.");
  }

}
```

Hope that helped!